# Multiple Charts on single page: iFrame versus Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp, iframe, jfreechart, bar-chart

Am trying to show multiple `Bar Charts` using `Jfreechart API` on a single page, all the charts from the same domain. Wondering if it would be better to use iFrames or are there any other alternatives? If i were to do this with Ajax, something like on page load show the bar charts in each `div's`, what would be the way to go about it? Would highly appreciate if anyone can throw more light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/) for web-based charting even over my own open source API [XChart](http://xeiam.com/xchart.jsp), which is geared more towards desktop applications. [Here](http://xeiam.com/helloflot.jsp) is a HelloWorld type example application with source code demonstrating Flot that I made at one point. If more you're more interested in fetching a JPEG containing a chart, you can see [how I do it with XChart](http://xeiam.com/xchart_examplecode.jsp) (Bonus Example, bottom of page), and you could probably do something very similar with `JFreeChart`.